# How to select from two selected tables in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to convert my SQL to Laravel Query Builder version, however I can't do that. Can anyone help me to solve this case or give me some advices, thank you.

Original SQL that work fine in mysql server.

```
SELECT Ifnull(no_of_accepted_job_offer, 0) AS no_of_accepted_job_offer
FROM   (SELECT job_name AS offer_job
        FROM   portal_setting) AS T1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(job_master.appno) AS no_of_accepted_job_offer,
                         job_master.offer_job
                  FROM   job_master
                         JOIN job_apply
                           ON job_master.appno = job_apply.appno
                  WHERE  job_apply.year = '2021'
                         AND job_master.status = 'accept'
                  GROUP  BY job_master.offer_job) AS T2
              ON T1.offer_job = T2.offer_job;
```

Converted the original SQL to Laravel Query Builder, but it doesn't work.

**Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '(select COUNT(job_master.appno)' doesn't exist**

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(SELECT job_name AS offer_job
        FROM   portal_setting) AS T1'))
->select(DB::raw('Ifnull(no_of_accepted_job_offer,0) AS no_of_accepted_job_offer'))
->leftJoin('(SELECT Count(job_master.appno) AS no_of_accepted_job_offer,
                         job_master.offer_job
                  FROM   job_master
                         JOIN job_apply
                           ON job_master.appno = job_apply.appno
                  WHERE  job_apply.year = \'2021\'
                         AND job_master.status = \'accept\'
                  GROUP  BY job_master.offer_job) AS T2','T1.offer_job','=','T2.offer_job')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB::table doesn't really work with subqueries.

But you can use `fromSub` and `joinSub`. These will take closures or query builder queries to be able to define your subqueries.

You can also access the query builder using DB::query() since you can't use a specific table.

You'll find each line of sql could be represented by a function in the query builder. It is worth looking through the documentation, or even the source code just to find all the functions.

So I came up with something like this:

```php
$joinSubQuery = DB::table('job_master')
    ->join('job_apply', 'job_master.appno', '=', 'job_apply.appno')
    ->where('job_apply.year', '2021')
    ->where('job_master.status', 'accept')
    ->groupBy('job_master.offer_job')
    ->select('job_master.offer_job')
    ->selectRaw('count(job_master.appno as no_of_accepted_job_offer');


DB::query()
    ->fromSub(function($query) {
        $query->from('portal_setting')
            ->select('job_name as offer_job');
    }, 'T1')
    ->leftJoinSub($joinSubQuery, 'T2', function($join) {
        $join->on('T1.offer_job', '=', 'T2.offer_job')
    })
    ->selectRaw('Ifnull(no_of_accepted_job_offer, 0) AS no_of_accepted_job_offer')
    ->get();
```